# How to create bitMap from imageUrl?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, uri, android-bitmap

I would like to create `bitmap` from imageUrl.
I have tried some solutions, but nothing works. How do you make it in Kotlin?

```
                    bitMap = Glide
                        .with(requireContext())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(imageUrlUri)
```

error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Bitmap?
Found:
RequestBuilder<Bitmap!>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bitMap = Glide
    .with(requireContext())
    .asBitmap()
    .load(imageUrl)
    .submit()
    .get()
```

Answer (score 0):

This method has been deprecated, but maybe help you:

```
bitmap = BitmapAsync().execute(your_image_url).get()!!
```

It will return you a bitmap.